Generic Windows Touchpad driver for linux
where can i find drivers for my touchpad (i am thinking of switching to Linux)
The driver that is being used by Windows is the generic I2C-HID mouse driver.

It’s likely you won’t need any drivers. If you’re thinking of switching, the best thing to do is use the USB media to ‘try Ubuntu’ (you’re given that option when you boot from the USB). Then you’ll find out if your touchpad (and other hardware) will work, without removing or damaging your current OS.

That's what i tried, The touchpad doesnt work

Thanks - put some details about your hardware in then please.

I have a Nokia Purebook Lite 14, not the most known laptop, the driver in Windows Device Manager says the touchpad is a generic mouse driver located in I2C-HID.
